# Integration of Tealium with Yahoo and Bing

Tags: tealium

How to integrate Tealium with Yahoo and Bing?
Which identifier to use? Kindly share the steps to integrate.

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo and Bing have multiple ways of collecting data across the platforms under their stack. Tealium allows ingesting data via the **client-side** tags or **server-side** connectors. Here is a list of available options and each of them accepts its own set of IDs.

Client-side tags:

1. Bing Ads Tag: [Tealium help doc](https://community.tealiumiq.com/t5/Client-Side-Tags/Bing-Ads-Microsoft-adCenter-Tag-Reference-Guide/ta-p/5689)
2. Yahoo DOT Tag: [Tealium help doc](https://community.tealiumiq.com/t5/Client-Side-Tags/Yahoo-Dot-Tag-Setup-Guide/ta-p/36282)
3. Yahoo Ads! Japan tag: [Tealium help doc](https://community.tealiumiq.com/t5/Client-Side-Tags/Yahoo-Japan-Site-General-Tag-Setup-Guide/ta-p/35281)
4. Generic tag containers are available to implement other applicable tags

Server-side Connectors:

1. Yahoo Data-X: [Tealium help doc](https://community.tealiumiq.com/t5/Server-Side-Connectors/Yahoo-DataX-Connector-Setup-Guide/ta-p/38041)
2. Yahoo Conversions Connector: [Tealium help doc](https://community.tealiumiq.com/t5/Server-Side-Connectors/Yahoo-Conversions-Connector-Setup-Guide/ta-p/38085)
3. Generic Webhook connectors are available to configure connectors to other platform's endpoints

Let me know if this is helpful or if you have further questions. Can you also share the specific platform under Yahoo or Bing that you are looking for help with? Happy to help :)